# Namespace declarations in web.config not being picked up after Converting to Web Application

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

I recently decided to convert my .Net Web Site to a Web Application. I followed the guidelines by creating a new Web Application, copying the files from my Web Site, including the files in my application and then selecting the option Convert to Web Application.

However since I have done that I have received hundreds of errors relating to namespaces, specifically the compiler can not resolve references in the  section of web.config.

Is there another solution to this apart from going through this large application and including the relevant Imports in each page code-behind?

I'm using .Net 4 and Visual Studio 2010

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to set full class name with assembly, for example:
"MyNamespace.MyClass, MyAssembly" (also you can set assembly version and key).